# Delete Row from Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel

I've been surfing the web for a while, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to delete rows from multiple sheets in the same workbook if they contain a keyword.

Sheet 1 (Overall) contains all the data, the following 5 sheets (QB, RB, WR, DEF, K) contain portions of the data from sheet 1 (Overall).

What I'd like to accomplish is to search for a name (e.g. Aaron Rodgers) and delete all rows from all sheets that contain that reference (so in the example above Aaron Rodgers rows would be delete from Overall **AND** QB because his name would appear on both of those sheets).

The name search will always be changing, so it's sort of a search and destroy rows containing the reference name of my choice from all sheets.

Comment: What aspect of the code are you struggling with? Please edit your question and post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. define the search string
2. define the parent workbook
3. loop through selected worksheets within that workbook
4. locate rows containing the search string and delete them

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub destroy()
    Dim str As String, w As Long, m As Variant, wss As Variant

    wss = Array("Overall", "QB", "RB", "WR", "DEF", "K")

    '1. define the search string
    str = Application.InputBox(prompt:="search for:", Title:="search and destroy", _
                             Default:="Aaron Rodgers", Type:=xlTextValues)

    If CBool(Len(str)) And str <> "False" Then

        '2. define the parent workbook
        With ThisWorkbook

            '3. loop through selected worksheets within that workbook
            For w = LBound(wss) To UBound(wss)
                With .Worksheets(wss(w))

                    '4. locate rows containing the search string and delete them
                    m = Application.Match(str, .Columns(1), 0)
                    Do While Not IsError(m)
                        .Cells(m, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                        m = Application.Match(str, .Columns(1), 0)
                    Loop

                End With
            Next w

        End With

    End If
End Sub
```